# How to display selected value on select drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a key value pair array:

```
FEEDBACK_NOTIFICATION = [['Only in reports', 'only_in_reports'],['Immediately', 'immediately']]
```

In my view I have tried:

```
<%= f.select(:feedback_schedule, FEEDBACK_NOTIFICATION, options ={:prompt => "-Select-"}) %>

<%= f.select(:feedback_schedule, options_for_select(FEEDBACK_NOTIFICATION), options ={:prompt => "-Select-"}) %>

<%= f.select(:feedback_schedule, options_for_select(FEEDBACK_NOTIFICATION, selected: feedback_schedule), options ={:prompt => "-Select-"}) %>
```

None of these seem to display the selected/updated value when I go back to the edit page even though the db has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

<%= f.select(:feedback_schedule, options_for_select(FEEDBACK_NOTIFICATION, selected: @object.feedback_schedule), options ={:prompt => "-Select-"}) %> will work